# Is there an iphone app that can send me push notifications from stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, notifications, iphone

Is it possible to get the stackoverflow notifications about answers, comments etc on my iphone with push notifications? is there an app that does that?

Comment: Check out http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, apparently [StackMate](https://stackapps.com/questions/2933/stackmate-for-ios) supports *some* push notifications (favourite questions, comments, answers on your questions). Note that this is a commercial app, priced at $0.99.

All the other [iphone tagged apps on StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/iphone) list push notifications as "coming in a future version".

I've only used [Six to Eight](https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store) myself but I find the mobile web interface to just as functional.